# running mocked method inside coroutine context returns null in kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, kotlin-coroutines

I want to mock a method of a service but this method is called inside a different context and returned value is null (dp.search is a suspend function). take a look at my code:

```
    @Test
    fun `testing mocked method in coroutine`() = testScope.runBlockingTest {
        val dp = Mockito.mock(DataProvider::class.java)
        Mockito.`when`(dp.search("Any")).thenReturn(listOf())

        val data = withContext(Dispatchers.Unconfined) { dp.search("Any")}
        // but data is null
        Assert.assertEquals(0, data.size)

    }
```

tried to check different situations like these two:

first not using dispatcher! just calling suspend function

```
    @Test
    fun `testing mocked method in coroutine`() = testScope.runBlockingTest {
        val dp = Mockito.mock(DataProvider::class.java)
        Mockito.`when`(dp.search("Any")).thenReturn(listOf())

        val data =  dp.search("Any")
        // but data is correct
        Assert.assertEquals(0, data.size)

    }
```

than mocking inside the defined context which mocks fine. (but it's not a solution.. just for checking if mock works)

```
    @Test
    fun `testing mocked method in coroutine`() = testScope.runBlockingTest {
        val dp = Mockito.mock(DataProvider::class.java)


        val data = withContext(Dispatchers.Unconfined) { 
                Mockito.`when`(dp.search("Any")).thenReturn(listOf())
                dp.search("Any")
        }
        //data is correct but this is not a solution for me. search is called in another class
        Assert.assertEquals(0, data.size)

    }
```

I should say that setup like this:

```
 @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    val testScope = TestCoroutineScope(testDispatcher)

  @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Before
    fun initialize() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testScope.cleanupTestCoroutines()

    }
```

Comment: Which mockito version are you using?

Comment: @sajad I've tried to reproduce your issue with Mockito 3.0.0 and this works fine https://pl.kotl.in/GfikthL1H